# How do you make VSCode Symbol Search find references in .virtualenv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I even opened the file directly and it still cannot find the symbol.

Before anyone asks, no it's not file exclusion settings. I've allowed file searches under `.virtualenv`, and regular string search works fine, but particularly Symbol Search (using the #) does not.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're now using a window to search for functions, methods, etc., and you're searching for strings in it. This of course doesn't exist because you don't have a method or variable named **ConvReLU2d** in your code.

[image]

If you need to search for strings, you can use `Ctrl+F` to search directly in the editor interface.

[image]

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Open Search Editor**. This will have a more detailed search.

[image]

This [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor) will help.